# How to automatically handle creation and update date on a Django model?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to have an immutable field(created_at) and be able to update it(updated_at) without altering the original created_at field. This is a django project if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield)).

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```